# TRIM forward slash in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code...

```
TRIM(LEADING '/' FROM ci.Long_description_1) as 'Description',
```

I am getting the error message

> Incorrect syntax near '/'

Whats the best way of writing this?

Thanks

Comment: That's not T-SQL syntax.

Comment: From SQL Server 2017, you may use `TRIM( '/' FROM ci.Long_description_1)`, but the character will be removed from the **start** and the **end** of the string.

Comment: Thanks guys I used https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-string-functions/sql-trim/ - yep Zhorov that works great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2017+, you may use `TRIM()` with a small trick (by default `TRIM()` removes the specified characters from the **start** and the **end** of the string):

```
SELECT LEFT(
   TRIM('/' FROM Long_description_1 + '?'),
   LEN(TRIM('/' FROM Long_description_1 + '?')) - 1
) AS Description   
FROM (VALUES
   (NULL),
   ('abcd'),
   ('1234/'),
   ('////abcd'),
   ('/folder/subfolder/x.yz')
) ci (Long_description_1)
```

Result:

```
Description
----------------------

abcd
1234/
abcd
folder/subfolder/x.yz
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to remove `'/'` if it is the first character of `Long_description_1` column value. `TRIM` function in `SQL Server` will not work the way you are expecting.

For this you can write your query like following.

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('/', ci.Long_description_1) = 1
            THEN RIGHT(ci.Long_description_1, LEN(ci.Long_description_1) - 1)
        ELSE ci.Long_description_1
        END AS [Description]
FROM YouTable
```

Comment: [`Trim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) removes _all_ occurrences of the specified character(s) from both ends of the string while your code will only remove one occurrence from the start. As a matter of performance it seems unnecessary to search for the location of the first solidus (`'/'`) and then check if it is at the start of the string rather than simply checking if `Left( ci.Long_description_1, 1 ) = '/'`.